# Replace IBOutlet view in code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, uistoryboard

I'm using storyboards and a tableview. Each cell in my tableview has a `UIView` in it. Is it possible to replace the `IBOutlet` of this `UIView` programmatically? For example doing something like this:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: UIView! /// Really this is a VIMVideoPLayerView (from library below) which inherits from UIView.

    func configureCell(with customObject: CustomObject) {

        // Set the IBOutlet in code here.
        self.videoPlayerView = customObject.videoPlayerView
    }
}
```

If I try to do this nothing happens.

I know many people will ask: "Why do you want to do this?". Here it goes: I am using this library [VIMVideoPlayer](https://github.com/vimeo/VIMVideoPlayer) and I create the actual player which contains a UIView in code. Instead of reusing the players I create them all at once in code and now want to display them. It really comes down to performance reasons regrading scrolling and lagging on main thread.

NOTE: I have this working in code already but really want to use storyboards. The way I have it working in code is by doing this:
`videoHolderView.addSubview(customObject.videoPlayerView)`

Any thoughts?

Comment: To summarize, you want to add a video playing subview.  You can add it yourself, but you'll need to add constraints in code, too.  Alternatively, you can add it as a subview of a view that was setup with constraints in IB.  There really aren't any other choices.  What I'd like to know is what's wrong with the subview option?  The question says "scrolling and lagging".  What's the problem there, and why would that problem go away if you abandon the outlet UIView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying the variable is fine, but that won't change the view hierarchy.
You will need to insert the new view into the original views superview, then remove the old view.
Keep in mind this will not retain any layout constraints, you will need to re-create them after adding the replacement view.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var videoPlayerView: UIView! /// Really this is a VIMVideoPLayerView (from library below) which inherits from UIView.

    func configureCell(with customObject: CustomObject) {
        // Replace the view by inserting a new view into the same location
        // in the view hierarchy
        let newVideoPlayerView = customObject.videoPlayerView
        videoPlayerView.superview.insertSubview(newVideoPlayerView, belowSubview: videoPlayerView)
        videoPlayerView.removeFromSuperview()

        // Set the IBOutlet in code here.
        videoPlayerView = newVideoPlayerView

        // TODO: Recreate your layout constraints
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm copying/pasting my comment from answer below here: Is there any way to do this without having to remove and then add constraints again? The benefit of the storyboard was because I have parallax and it depends on some constraints so I wouldn't get much benefit here switching to storyboards.

Comment: No, but you can simplify the constraints by using another view as a wrapper, which only contains this single child view you intend to replace. You could then add simple top/left/bottom/right constraints to that parent view.

Comment: I see, I don't really see any benefits in doing this then. Do you think there are any benefits here with this storyboard approach? Again, what I'm doing currently is creating the views in code and then doing `videoHolderView.addSubview(customObject.videoPlayerView)`

Comment: I couldn't say if there are any benefits to using storyboards in this particular case, that really depends on what else you may be doing for this design. In general I'd recommend doing what feels like the right approach to you. Both approaches are equally valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but all your current code is doing is updating the property.  You need to remove the existing view from the view hierarchy and add the new view as a sub-view.

```
func configureCell(with customObject: CustomObject) {

    // Set the IBOutlet in code here.

    self.videoPlayerView.removeFromSuperview()

    self.videoPlayerView = customObject.videoPlayerView

    self.addSubView(self.videoPlayerView)

}
```

Note that you may also have to add any constraints that are required for the new view

Comment: Is there any way to do this without having to remove and then add constraints again? The benefit of the storyboard was because I have parallax and it depends on some constraints so I wouldn't get much benefit here switching to storyboards.